# Why flashing Arduino Leonardo clone from Eclipse C++ IDE for Arduino is failing?

Tags: eclipse, arduino, usb

I tried to setup a current Eclipse CDT (Photon) in order to program a Micro strong (5V) that is an Arduino Leonardo clone. Arduino functionality was preinstalled which surprised me. Adding a launch target is pretty easy. The compiling of code is working but when trying to flash to a leonardo clone the process is stuck reporting the following in the console:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:/Users/zephr/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM5
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Anyone an idea what is causing the problem here ? The process is running smooth in the original Arduino IDE. Further on, where can I find the options that are sent to avrdude in eclipse settings ? I cant find anything in the build options...

Greetings...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about opening it's serial port with 1200bps bitrate. This specific bitrate is used to do software reset and rebooting the board into the bootloader, so the arduino can be reprogrammed.

And another catch is that the bootloader resides on another COM port than the sketch. Thats why the Arduino IDE touches the board's port on 1200bps and then checks changes on COM port interfaces. After it detects correct port, it starts flashing.

For example debug info from Micro board:

```
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port COM6
PORTS {COM6, } / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {COM7, } => {COM7, }
Found upload port: COM7
C:\arduino-1.8.5\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\arduino-1.8.5\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -PCOM7 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_998217/sketch_sep02a.ino.hex:i
```

Comment: Interesting, perhaps this is not implemented yet in Eclipse for Arduino....

Comment: I found a batch file that adresses this problem here https://github.com/p1ne/arduino-leonardo-uploader. Any idea how to change the toolchain so that this batch is called instead of avrdude ?

Comment: Modified the leonardo uploader a little bit: https://github.com/zephram2015/avrdude_autoreset_wrapper so it will enable building and uploading in one step from the run command in the IDE.